# Particles and gravity

Tags: particles

I don't really know how to search for what I'm looking for which is why I think it'll be easier to ask on here.

I'm creating a webpage and I had the idea of having random glowing particles floating around in the background. I've created something extremely basic where they spawn and then respawn when they go off the edge, however it doesn't really look very realistic and I wanted to have a similar effect to the intro screen in FF14:A Realm Reborn where the particles seamlessly float along in complete randomness but they do it in a way that looks so natural as if they're being brushed around by wind.

I don't really know where to begin on reading about this. I'm not really looking for a code solution, I want to create my own, instead what I'd prefer are explanations or links to guides that can get me started. Most of the particle systems I look up are just particle systems and they don't have this added gravity feel and I'm not really sure where to quickly learn about this specifically.

Comment: Could you post a link to a video of the FF intro screen you mentioned?  It's hard to know what you mean without an example to watch.

Comment: Are you talking about *gravity* as in pulling objects down? Or are you talking about *substance* as in it *feels* real? One of them is a technical property that can easily be remedied, the other is an artistic property that's more difficult to define and remedy.

Comment: From your description it sounds like the word you are looking for is "inertia" and not "gravity"

Comment: Or 1D Perlin noise to modify the instant velocity of each particle.. as seen here: http://vimeo.com/2826441

Comment: The 1D perlin thing seemed similar to what I'm looking for. Is here the example you asked for:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5A4WYycS5Rc

There aren't many but if you look in the background there are particles floating around and they do so in a very natural way, the natural part is what i'm struggling with.